# Question Regarding Rank Theorem and Local Properties

Tags: real-analysis

I am still trying to understand the Rank theorem and how it can be used.

For example, if I am understanding it correctly, we have that if $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m
$,  which is $C^1$, and rank$(Df(x))=n$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then $f$ is locally injective and if rank$(Df(x))=m$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ then $f$ is locally surjective.

I know that the derivative having full rank at a point implies it will have full rank in a neighborhood of that point, hence the Rank theorem will apply. I also understand that with constant rank in a neighborhood the intuition is that the function "looks like" the derivative locally (so injective derivative $\implies$ injective function), but how does one show rigorously the above assertion about local injectivity and surjectivity from the Rank theorem? Thanks!

Here is the formulation of the Rank theorem I am referencing from my professors notes:

Let $f:U\to\mathbb{R}^m$ where $U \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a mapping of $C^k$, $k\geq 1$. Suppose that the rank$(Df(x_0))= N$ for all points in a neighborhood of $x_0$. Then there is a diffeomorphism $\Phi$ in a neighborhood of $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and a diffeomorphism $\Psi$ in a neighborhood of $f(x_0) \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that

$$(\Psi \circ f \circ \Phi ^{-1})(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(x_1,\dots,x_N, 0 ,\dots, 0)$$

In a neighborhood of $\Phi (x_0)$

Comment: The theorem asserts that in  nbhds $U$, and $V$ of $x_0$ and $f(x_0)$ resp, there are coordinate systems for which $f$ "looks like" a projection ($n\ge m$) or an inclusion ($n\le m$). Which makes sense because if we think of $f$ as locally Euclidean, then $\Psi$ and $\Phi$ are locally changes of bases in $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @Matematleta Thanks for explaining the intuition behind the theorem in a different way, that definitely adds some understanding to the Rank theorem. Can you show rigorously using the above theorem statement (or a similar variation) what you just explained? I need to avoid phrases like "looks like", when using the Rank theorem in a proof.

Comment: It's just a local change of coordinates in the domain and then the inverse function theorem gives a local change of coordinates in the range. I like [Lee's proof](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-9982-5), but there are many [proofs of this](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ghomi/LectureNotes/LectureNotes6G.pdf)  you can find on the internet. But the best way to see what is going on IMO, is to sit down and try to write out a proof yourself. Then, if you get stuck, consult the links.